# How to create a Google calendar event with hangoutLink (Google meet)

Tags: laravel, google-calendar-api, google-contacts-api, google-meet

i'am using `spatie/laravel-google-calendar` package to create event with meeting but it only create event without meeting, i merged [this commit](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-google-calendar/pull/174/commits/8dd4844d4bc5c8450a168234a53f81e5b9911290)

but it didn't work 'still create event without meeting'.
this is `createFromGoogleCalendarEvent` method of `event.php` file

```
public static function createFromGoogleCalendarEvent(Google_Service_Calendar_Event $googleEvent, $calendarId)
    {

        // this option are to create a conference and add a link to meet in event
        $googleCalendar = static::getGoogleCalendar($calendarId);
        $service = $googleCalendar->getService();
        $conference = new \Google_Service_Calendar_ConferenceData();
        $conferenceRequest = new \Google_Service_Calendar_CreateConferenceRequest();
        $conferenceRequest->setRequestId('randomString123');
        $conference->setCreateRequest($conferenceRequest);
        $googleEvent->setConferenceData($conference);
        $googleEvent = $service->events->patch($calendarId, $googleEvent->id, $googleEvent, ['conferenceDataVersion' => 1]);

        $event = new static;

        $event->googleEvent = $googleEvent;
        $event->calendarId = $calendarId;

        return $event;
    }
```

and this is my code to create event

```
$event = new Spatie\GoogleCalendar\Event;
$event->name = 'A new event';
$event->description = 'Event description';
$event->startDateTime = Carbon\Carbon::now();
$event->endDateTime = Carbon\Carbon::now()->addHour();
$event->save();
```

and this is my response

```
{
  anyoneCanAddSelf: null,
  attendeesOmitted: null,
  colorId: null,
  created: "2021-04-06T11:54:35.000Z",
  description: "Event description",
  endTimeUnspecified: null,
  etag: ""3235420151680000"",
  eventType: "default",
  guestsCanInviteOthers: null,
  guestsCanModify: null,
  guestsCanSeeOtherGuests: null,
  hangoutLink: null,
  htmlLink: "https://www.google.com/calendar/event?eid=dXZyNHByamc0ZXNqbDkxajI5c3I0cWI3c28gZGxvcW45M2VoOWlsZm5lOWRjb2xodDY5aWtAZw",
  iCalUID: "uvr4prjg4esjl91j29sr4qb7so@google.com",
  id: "uvr4prjg4esjl91j29sr4qb7so",
  kind: "calendar#event",
  location: null,
  locked: null,
  privateCopy: null,
  recurrence: null,
  recurringEventId: null,
  sequence: 0,
  status: "confirmed",
  summary: "A new event",
  transparency: null,
  updated: "2021-04-06T11:54:35.840Z",
  visibility: null,
  creator: {
    displayName: null,
    email: "mohamed-service-account@mohamed-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
    id: null,
    self: null
  },
  organizer: {
    displayName: "Mohamed calendar",
    email: "dloqn93eh9ilfne9dcolht69ik@group.calendar.google.com",
    id: null,
    self: true
  },
  start: {
    date: null,
    dateTime: "2021-04-06T13:54:35+02:00",
    timeZone: null
  },
  end: {
    date: null,
    dateTime: "2021-04-06T14:54:35+02:00",
    timeZone: null
  },
  reminders: {
    useDefault: true
  }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to stack please read [ask] edit your question and include [example] you are missing the authorization code.   Also please tell us what you mean by "Doesnt work"  do you have an error message what is the response.

Comment: @DaImTo I modified the explanation of my question and added response.

Comment: what's wrong with it?

Comment: @DaImTo i tried to create meeting at google meet using google calendar api but it only create event without create meeting and (hangoutLink) value of my response is null, this is my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this issue by replacing `service account` authentication with `oauth`.

- https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/php
- https://github.com/spatie/laravel-google-calendar#authentication-with-oauth2
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pOdgE22D-1U&t=730s